# Django Nose ImportError: no modules named urls

Tags: django, nose, nosetests, django-1.4, django-nose

I started using django-nose because I wanted to to run only my apps' tests via python manage.py test, but I'm running into this ImportError: no modules named urls.

This project is using Django 1.4.

The folder structure is like so:

```
project
├── manage.py
├── project
    ├── apps
    │   ├── app1
    |       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── tests.py
    │   └── app2
    │   └── app3
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

However, when I run python manage.py test, I get an ImportError: no module named urls:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 89, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 21, in process_request
    check_path = self.is_language_prefix_patterns_used()
  File "/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 54, in is_language_prefix_patterns_used
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
  File "/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 328, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 323, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 38, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named urls
```

Things I have tried that didn't work:

1. Per the Django-nose docs, tried killing **init**.py from the outer project folder. This didn't change anything.
2. Tried setting up everything in a fresh virtualenvironment.
3. I went into importlib.py and added printed out the name, package, and sys.path:

> ```
> name: project.urls
> package: None
> sys.path: 
> ‘/Users/huey/code’
> ‘/Users/huey/code/project’ 
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python27.zip’
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python2.7’  
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin’
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python2.7/plat-mac’
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages’
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python2.7/lib-tk’
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python2.7/lib-old’
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload’
> ‘/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7’
> ‘/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin’
> ‘/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk'
> ‘/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac’
> ‘/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages’
> ‘/Users/huey/.virtualenvs/projectfresh/lib/python2.7/site-packages’
> ‘/Users/huey/code/project/project/apps’
> ‘/Users/huey/code/project/project/common’
> ‘/Users/huey/code/project/project/lib’
> ```

ROOT_URLCONF is 'project.urls'

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Even though I removed **init**.py, I forgot to remove its corresponding .pyc file.